# Can a SYSTEM process share data with a non-SYSTEM process?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, clipboard, shared-memory

I'm trying to use `QSharedMemory` and `QClipboard` to share data between a `SYSTEM` process (running on the `WinSta0\\Winlogon` desktop) and a normal user process, but both fail to share data with others `non-SYSTEM` processes running on the normal desktop. I belive this is because the `WinSta0\\Winlogon` desktop is a isolated desktop.

My app is a program that takes shots of the Windows Secure Desktop and send it to clipboard.

The question is: Is there any way to share memory data between that process and `non-SYSTEM` processes? (Actually I'm using a file to do the job).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Vista and later, system services run in an isolated session ("session 0").  This is the most likely cause of your problem.  (Note that all system services run in session 0, regardless of whether they are running in the `SYSTEM` security context or not.  Similarly, it is possible to launch processes as `SYSTEM` in an arbitrary session.)

Each session has a separate `WinSta0` workstation, and hence a separate clipboard.  So clipboard functionality is not going to work here.

It is possible for file mapping objects (shared memory) to work across session boundaries.  However, I don't know whether it is possible to do this with Qt.  The best bet would appear to be to use `setNativeKey` which presumably determines the name of the file mapping; to make a file mapping cross session boundaries, use a name that begins with `Global\` as described in the [MSDN article on CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If possible, consider using the Win32 API directly rather than Qt.